# How do I flip this "grid" of displayed objects to be in 3x2 instead of 2x3

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I am trying to show the user a bunch of data based on a grid (not the ui element grid). The data changes and the displayed instances are based on the X/Y position of that data. I used an example I found here (but can't find it right now) and I basically got everything working. Except that the displayed grid is on it's side. I have created a test project under which I'm trying to make the thing work correctly before taking that to my main project.

[Here is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABRAf.png)

[Here is what I want it to look like (Tanks Paint)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tid8i.png)

**Codebehind:** (Quick and dirty but works for testing purposes)

```
private DataContainer[][] dataArray;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            dataArray = new DataContainer[3][];
            dataArray[0] = new DataContainer[2];
            dataArray[1] = new DataContainer[2];
            dataArray[2] = new DataContainer[2];
            dataArray[0][0] = new DataContainer(1,"At: 0,0");
            dataArray[1][0] = new DataContainer(2, "At: 1,0");
            dataArray[2][0] = new DataContainer(3, "At: 2,0");
            dataArray[0][1] = new DataContainer(4, "At: 0,1");
            dataArray[1][1] = new DataContainer(5, "At: 1,1");
            dataArray[2][1] = new DataContainer(6, "At: 2,1");
            InitializeComponent();

            lst.ItemsSource = dataArray;
        }
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level2">
            <Border Name="border" BorderBrush="LightGreen" BorderThickness="5"
          Padding="2" Margin="2" Width="80">
                <Grid Margin="2">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border Name="border2" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2"
                                                Grid.Row ="0" Padding="1" Margin="1">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Border Name="border3" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2"
                                                Grid.Row ="1" Padding="1" Margin="1">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Number1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level1">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level2}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="lst" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level1}"/>
    </Grid>
```

**What I've tried:**
I tried changing stackpanel orientation to Vertical. That got me half way there. The Result is left column on top of right column. The problem is changing the 3 elements within that column to be Horizontal, which should give the result I'm looking for.

I also triend fondling the DataTemplate_Level2 but that just left me with error messages.

To be honest, I'm new to WPF (in case you haven't noticed) This databinding and templating is the most complicated UI part of my project and I've been thoroughly confused by trying to learn all the stuff at once. I would appreciate it if someone would point me towards an answer here. It's almost Christmas and I would much rather not spend the holidays thinking about this problem.

One solution I can think of is swapping the X and Y coordinates in the array to be dataArray[Y][X] instead of dataArray[X][Y] but that would make things difficult for me in the future and it would be best to get the problems solved now.

In case you wonder what the datacontainer object looks like, but this **shouldn't be important to the solution of this issue**. it's just something I whipped together to demonstrate that I have gotten the binding and updating to work. It just displays the coordinates it should be at and at random interval changes the value of the number:

```
public class DataContainer : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int number1 = 0;
        private string text1 = "none";
        private System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public DataContainer(int num,string str)
        {
            number1 = num;
            text1 = str;
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(num*1000);
            aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            aTimer.AutoReset = true;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
        private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            number1 = r.Next(0, 100);
            number1 += 1;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Number1");
        }
        public int Number1
        {
            get { return this.number1; }
            set
            {
                if (this.number1 != value)
                {
                    this.number1 = value;
                    this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Number1");
                }
            }
        }
        public string Text1
        {
            get { return this.text1; }
            set
            {
                if (this.text1 != value)
                {
                    this.text1 = value;
                    this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Text1");
                }
            }
        }
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: looks like you can use `UniformsGrid Columns="3" Rows="2"` and put 6 items in ItemsControl

Answer (score 0):

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    lst.ItemsSource = new List<DataContainer>
    {
        new DataContainer(1, "At: 0,0"),
        new DataContainer(2, "At: 1,0"),
        new DataContainer(3, "At: 2,0"),
        new DataContainer(4, "At: 0,1"),
        new DataContainer(5, "At: 1,1"),
        new DataContainer(6, "At: 2,1")
    }
}

<ItemsControl x:Name="lst" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level2}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <UniformsGrid Columns="3" Rows="2"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately it's not what I'm looking for since I'm trying to avoid lists for a reason and the amount of columns and rows may change dynamically. It's my own fault for not being more clear about that. Fortunately I did find an answer myself so problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

I had some sleep and tested out some things and figured out where exactly things are going wrong by adding more borders. Here's the solution that I found myself:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="lst" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level1}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
 </ItemsControl>
```

and the data template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level1">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level2}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
 </DataTemplate>
```